# combobox selected value changes before submitting the form

Tags: c, web, combobox, cgi

I use CGI C and try to use a combobox in a form. When i change selected value and press save button, before submitting the form i can see the selected value changes. It becomes 7 always. I can not find out why. Here is my code:

```
<form method=POST action="cgi-bin/aa.cgi?aa.xml" name="aform" onsubmit="return checkConForm(document.aform);">
    <table class=conftable>
            <td class=conftabletd>
            <select name="aa" id="aa" >
            <option value=2>2</option><option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <a href="javascript:submitform(document.aform)" class="more">save</a>
</form>
```

js :

```
function checkConfigForm ( form )
{

   var selectLists = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
   for ( var i=0; i<selectLists.length; i++ ) {
       if (selectLists[i].id != null) {
         alert(selectLists[i].id);
         selectOpts(selectLists[i].id);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function selectOpts( selectId )
{
  var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
  var selectListLength = selectList.length;
  if (selectListLength == 0){
    appendOptionLastwValue( selectId, "" );
    selectListLength = 1;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < selectListLength; i++) {
    selectList.options[i].selected = true;
  }
  return true;
}


function submitform( form )
{
     if(form.onsubmit() == true){
     form.submit();
}
```

Comment: This looks fine, except for the missing \ in the the first printf. Maybe you should post the rest of the code related to `save`?

Comment: And is the problem only visual or do you also get 7 and not the value selected?

Comment: I edit the code with the source code. And yes i get 7 if i choose even numbers and get 6 for odd numbers.

Comment: Do you care to post the actual __code__ of what happens, and not just the `<form>`?

Comment: I have just edit my js codes, also. I am tracking but still can not solve the problem.

Comment: You have missed <tr> opening tag after <table class=conftable> into your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are setting every option of the SELECT object to TRUE here one after another:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectListLength; i++) {
    selectList.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

after submitting the form, the last option ( options[6] = 7 ) being selected as the result.